# Is there a specific reason Delta Airlines is allowed to have a call sign that's also code word in the NATO phonetic alphabet?

Tags: radio-communications, call-sign

This is a followup to [Is there any specific reason why Delta Air Lines doesn't have its own callsign?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/72127/is-there-any-specific-reason-why-delta-air-lines-doesnt-have-its-own-callsign) I was... "helpfully" informed that, um, actually, Delta Airlines *does* have its own callsign, it's "Delta".

So, let me try this again.

Having an airline callsign be the same as a letter code word in the NATO alphabet creates a huge potential for misunderstanding. Indeed, the controllers at Atlanta, Delta's headquarters, use "Dixie" for the letter "D", specifically to avoid ambiguity with the name of the airline. It seems to me that it would be much simpler to just assign the airline a different callsign. Is there any specific reason why this hasn't been done?

Comment: This is a request for clarification: Who says flights are not allowed to have a phonetic call sign (the conclusion from the question since DAL is *allowed*)? For example: a general aviation traffic uses its registration (tail number) as its call sign in phonetic pronunciation, which is normal.

Comment: In other words, and based on the previous answers, the only factual answer is *it is **not not** allowed.* Does it cause issues? Sure, not just DAL; Skybrary has a whole article on [call sign confusion](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Call-sign_Confusion). If I have misunderstood something, let me know, or edit the question body.

Comment: @ymb1, well, all in that article suggests that Delta should change their call-sign to avoid similarity with German aircraft using their tail numbers (which start with D).

Comment: I don't see how this is an issue at all. There's little chance of confusion for an aircraft whose callsign contains a "D" (November seven two two charlie delta) being confused, even with "Delta seven-twenty-two". If N722CD were a potential problem, I'd use his aircraft type rather than "November".